# Palette created by my code doesn't work

Tags: front-end, palettes

I think I am lost on some basic issue ...

I created two CellTags, tagone and tagtwo

If I create this palette inputting the following code by hand I get a beautifully working palette that makes me jump to these cells.

```
 CreatePalette[{
    Button["tagone", NotebookFind[InputNotebook[], "tagone", All, CellTags]], 
    Button["tagtwo", NotebookFind[InputNotebook[], "tagtwo", All, CellTags]]}]
```

If I do put this in a function like the following the palette gets created with right names shown in the buttons, but pressing the buttons nothing happens ... 
Apparently there is a problem in this code with the use of the counter variable in the `For`. In this examples it is called `celln` and in the error monitor I get

> Part specification celln$53002 is neither a machine-sized integer nor a list of machine-sized integers.

I though the variables was fixed in the loop ... I am quite puzzled, any guess? Did I just made a rookie mistake? I think this functions was previously working when I originally developed it in December. Maybe my memory is failing.

```
 Module[{nb, res, list, origlist, celln},
   nb = InputNotebook[];
   origlist = NotebookTools`NotebookCellTags[nb];
   Print[origlist];
   res = {};
   For[celln = 1, celln <= Length[origlist], celln++,
     Print[ToString[origlist[[celln]]]];
     AppendTo[res, 
      Button[origlist[[celln]],
        NotebookFind[nb, origlist[[celln]], All, CellTags, AutoScroll -> True]]];
   ];
   CreatePalette[res];
 ]
```

Comment: I keep trying variations and it seems like the variable `nb` and the one for the name of the tag are messed up ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm always suspicious of code using `For`, so I rewrote your code in a more functional way. It seems to wrong fine.

```
Module[{tags, buttons},
  tags = NotebookTools`NotebookCellTags[InputNotebook[]];
  buttons = 
    Button[#, NotebookFind[InputNotebook[], #, All, CellTags, AutoScroll -> True]] & /@ tags;
  CreatePalette[buttons];]
```

I had two cells in my test notebook with tags: `tag-1` and `tag-2`. The palette created looks this:

[image: palette]

Clicking on one of the buttons scrolls to the indicated cell and selects it.

Comment: You are right, `For` is an enemy ... I have done essentially the same rewrite using `Map` as you did too. So pissed by `For` ...